# Linked Server against similar Text files

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, linked-server, ini

I have a Link Server that goes against 6 text files. I have an ini that describes the text files.

So for example I have

- 20101231 - 01.txt
- 20101231 - 02.txt
- 20101231 - 03.txt
- 20101231 - 04.txt
- 20101231 - 05.txt
- 20101231 - 06.txt

Then I have 20110101... 20110102... etc.

Using notepad++, to edit the ini, I change all 20101231 to 20110101... 0102... etc. This isn't a tedious process, but it does take time each time I need to do this.

I'm still relatively new to Linked Servers... is there a way to describe files "dynamically" to cover situations like this? So that I can describe files that end with "- 01.txt"? I've been looking and just don't see an answer either way saying this is possible/impossible.

Comment: You said "I use notepad++ and just change all 20101231 to 20101231" that is the same date... was that a typo?

Comment: Yeah. Some of this stuff makes me cross eye'd. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2007/08/how-to-give-alias-to-sql-linked-server.html) for aliasing Linked Servers.  The directions are written for a linked SQL server, however your situation should be similar.